# setInterval returns undefined OR scope of returned value wrong

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, scope, setinterval

I try to store Date.now() after a setIntervall invoked a callback. After that, I'd like to clear the intervall, so it only fires once. All that in a class.
But the variable I store the intervalID in and I hoped would be available "class-wide"  keeps "undefined". I am pretty sure I am doing sth awfully wrong with JS scope, but I cannot find out what.

```
class Signal {
    t : number;
    private intervallId : number | undefined;
    
    
    constructor(t : number) {
        this.t = t;
              
    }

    wait() {
        
        this.intervallId = setInterval(this.signalTriggered, this.t)
        console.log("Never executed.")
    }

    signalTriggered() {
        const triggerTime : number = Date.now()
        console.log(this.intervallId) /* always undefined */
        if (this.intervallId) {clearInterval(this.intervallId)
        console.log(triggerTime); }
    }
}

var timer = new Signal(2000)
    timer.wait()
    console.log("Done.") /* Never printed out. */
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce *`console.log("Never executed.")`* or *`/* Never printed out. */`*. But yes, `this` in your callback is not bound to the `timer` instance.

Comment: "*I'd like to clear the intervall, so it only fires once*" - then use `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the reference of the `this`, you are losing the original reference of it when passing the method as an argument to `setIterval`.
You could use an arrow function to wrap the method:

```js
setInterval(() => this.signalTriggered(), this.t)
```

Or use `Function.prototype.bind` to assign the reference of `this`:

```js
setInterval(this.signalTriggered.bind(this), this.t)
```